# How do I find out which users/installations account for percentage of requests in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Parse app and I want to find out which users/installations account for requests. There is a spike in API request activity in my app, and I'm suspicious of some users/devices that may be sending too many requests (either intentionally or due to a bug). How do I find that out? Here is a spike in usage:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I know of that you might be able to see what's going on, and what might be causing that massive spike you're seeing.

1. Head to the Analytics section for your app (that the screenshot you provided was generated from). In the left pane, under Performance, you should see Requests and Queries submenu items. If you click on Queries, and then set the date range to 19th April (when your spike was experienced), you should be able to see the Classes and Queries that generated the traffic. There is a handy count field, so this should give you a clue as to the requests on the server. However, this doesn't tell you who was requesting - just what the requests were - but this information might be useful in tracking down any bugs.
2. If you want to see what Installations have been generating the most requests, click on "Explorer" in the left pane (this is quite new functionality). From here, you can see specific information about users and requests. There is a handy Saved Query that you can use to see which users have been generating traffic. Click on "Top Installations Yesterday", then change the date range to be the date of your traffic spike, and change "Group By" to be "Parse User ID". Click "Run Query" and you should see the User ID of the user who has been generating the bulk of the traffic at the top.

If the user causing the hassle is anonymous, then I think the User ID will be empty. And if that's what you're seeing, you could have a malicious user on your hands :-(

Hope that helps!

Comment: the second one showed me a suspicious installation ID with 3K queries, way higher than any other, pointing to a specific Android device. I'll be contacting the owner of that device, it's probably a bug that put something into a bad recursion, rather than a malicious/intentional thing.